# According to Ramban, why is גזל part of the ז מצות בני נח?

Tags: gentiles, gezel-stealing, noachide-laws, ramban

One of the ז מצות בני נח is דינים. According to the Ramban on parshat [vayishlach (34:13)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.34.13?lang=en&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Genesis.34.13.1&lang2=en)

> the laws that were counted [as one] of the seven commandments that the Children of Noach were commanded is not only to set up judges in each and every town, but [rather] He commanded them in the laws of theft and fraud, abuse, fair wages, laws of guardianship, rape and seduction, the main categories of damages, injury to ones's fellow, laws of the borrower and lender, laws of purchase and sale and similar to them

It means that the non-jews have to make laws about man to man transgressions. One of his examples are theft. So according to this, why is there a separate issur of גזל as one of the ז מצות בני נח, if it is included in the mitzvah of דינים?

Comment: דינים makes it legally punishable, but it doesn't make it intrinsically forbidden.

Comment: The mitzva of dinim, according to the Ramban, is to set up a system that would adjudicate all of these matters, but it does not create a specific prohibition on theft. The Ramban there himself says that the mitzva of dinim is a mitzvas aseh and would not warrant a death penalty. The specific commandment against theft makes it into an “Azhara” which receives the death penalty.